# How to update a widget using a service

Tags: java, android, service, widget, broadcastreceiver

**Need to update TextView of a clock widget every second or every time the minute changes ..**

I am calling the service from onReceive of my AppWidgetProvider :

```
 private String action = "clock.beautiful.best.com.mmclock.TheService";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);


 //UseThis


    Log.e("h","R");


    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);

    // Create a fresh intent
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TheService.class);

   serviceIntent.setAction(action);

   context.startService(serviceIntent);


    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, TheService.class);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);




}
```

What should i do to check for update in time and if there is a then update the 'time' TextView..

Service :

```
public class TheService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e("Service","created");



}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.e("Service","Destroy");

}

public void changeYexy (){

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(TheService.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.dateTextView,"T");



}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.e("Service","start");


    }
}
```

I don't want users to open the activity again and again to update , is there any way i can check and update the time from service or widget..

Any kind of is really really really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using service you can use AlarmManager to update widget periodically

```
public class Alarm
{
    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int interval)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, yourWidget.class);
        intent.setAction("WIDGET_UPDATE");
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
                .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, yourWidget.class));
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval * 1000, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

in this way the alram send a broadCast to widget with "WIDGET_UPDATE" as action after interval seconds.

Enable the alarm in onEnable method of your widget:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    Alarm.setAlarm(context, 1);

}
```

In the onReceive method of yourWidget update yourWidget and set the alarm for next time

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if ("WIDGET_UPDATE".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
                    .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, yourWidget.class));

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        //set alarm for the next time
        Alarm.setAlarm(context, 1);

        //update your widget here
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);      

    }
}
```

**Note** : although it is possile to use setRepeating instead of setExact but for me it does not work properly